# Range object in word API with Track Changes

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am struggling with the Range object in the Word API, especially combined with track changes.

I built a solution where one user can select text in a word document. I use a database to store the start- and end position of these selected words/sentences. These words will get highlighted when the user opens a document. However, if we start track changes, those ranges does not map anymore to the correct location in the document. I really cannot find a way to do this mapping and your help is really appreciated. Is there even a way to do this?

I tried a lot of things already:

```
_wordDocument.ShowRevisions = false;
_wordDocument.TrackRevisions = false;
_wordDocument.TrackFormatting = false;
_wordDocument.TrackMoves = false;

_wordDocument.ActiveWindow.View.RevisionsView = WdRevisionsView.wdRevisionsViewOriginal;
_wordDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowRevisionsAndComments = false;
_wordDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowInsertionsAndDeletions = false;

_wordDocument.Saved = false;
_wordDocument.Save();

//Do what we need to do
range = _wordDocument.Range(ref startRange, ref endRange);

string theTextInRange = range.Text;
MessageBox.Show("Text in range: " + theTextInRange);

_wordDocument.Bookmarks.Add(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "_{0}", commentViewModel.CommentId), range);

//Revert back (do after)
_wordDocument.ShowRevisions = _lastShowRevisions;
_wordDocument.TrackRevisions = true;
_wordDocument.TrackFormatting = _lastTrackFormatting;
_wordDocument.TrackMoves = true;

_wordDocument.ActiveWindow.View.RevisionsView = WdRevisionsView.wdRevisionsViewFinal;
_wordDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowRevisionsAndComments = true;
_wordDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowInsertionsAndDeletions = true;

_wordDocument.Saved = false;
_wordDocument.Save();
```

So as you can see, I use bookmarks to hard-store the position of the comments the next time I open the document, but that range doesn't map anymore if the user changed the document in the meantime (my implementation supports multiple copies so it means that user B can highlight stuff in a copied version and that those highlightings are also shown in document B where we try to create bookmarks like I showed in the code above).